# Excel-VBA-hide row-in protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`
`For a = 13 To 33`
`If Worksheets("Heating Coil").Cells(a, 5).Value = "0"`  `Then`
`Worksheets("Heating Coil").Rows(a).Hidden = True`
`End If`
`Next`
`End Sub`
`Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()`
`For a = 13 To 33`
`If Worksheets("Heating Coil").Cells(a, 5).Value = "0"`  `Then`
`Worksheets("Heating Coil").Rows(a).Hidden = False`
`End If`
`Next`
`End Sub`

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok3Us.jpg)Please help to hide a row that contains zero in particular cell of that row,

I have tried with VBA later protected that sheet with password (not through VBA)

my command button working for unprotected sheet, but not working while I am protecting the same sheet with password

So Please some one help me to hide rows based on the value in column E (if it is equal to zero), for my protected work sheet

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you're trying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @BigBen don't know to add code, so i have added picture Link, please check and help me if possible

Comment: Just [edit] your question (paste the code as text). We can help fix the formatting if needed.

Comment: Edited with code